# Different default remote for pull and push, while allowing manually specifying one

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

I have a local Git repository that has two remotes. `origin` is a fork of `upstream`. I work on `master`. I would like to achieve this:

- `git pull` is equivalent to `git pull upstream master`
- `git push` is equivalent to `git push origin master`
- `git pull origin master` pulls from `origin`
- `git push upstream master` pushes to `upstream`

So the workflow to sync `origin` with `upstream` would be simplified to

```
git pull  # from upstream
git push  # to origin
```

I've managed to configure the first part with the following result from a series of `git config` commands:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = upstream
    merge = refs/heads/master
    pushRemote = origin
```

However, `git push` gives me this error:

```
fatal: You are pushing to remote 'origin', which is not the upstream of
your current branch 'master', without telling me what to push
to update which remote branch.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Git are you running? Did you change the `push.default` setting? In Git >= 2.0, this should have worked, unless you've configured some other `push.default` setting.

Comment: @torek I'm using Git 2.17 and I was expecting that value to default to `simple` when it's not present. However, my problem was solved after expliciting specifying `push.default = simple`. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Interesting. It seems like it should have worked without an explicit `push.default` setting. I will post that as an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually supposed to work "out of the box" in Git versions >= 2.0, the way you configured things.

Apparently, per comments, you also have to explicitly configure `push.default` to `simple`, even though that's the default for an unconfigured `push.default`.  (Setting `push.default` to `current` would also work, but would remove the safety check that `simple` adds for some pushes.)

Note that you can set the upstream of any branch using `git branch --set-upstream-to`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/master master
```

but it does take a `git config` command (or direct editing of the config file—I like to use `git config --edit` myself often, especially to fix typos) to set the `pushRemote` as well, which you need for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

One option, though not exactly what you requested, would be to define aliases for the various commands, in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias gpull='git pull upstream master'
alias gpush='git push origin master'
```

Then, just use these aliases as you would any normal UNIX alias.  I vote against trying to change the semantics of the base Git commands, partly because I don't know how, but also partly because it could lead to confusion down the road at some point.